# Find attribute values in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to Selenium 2.0 and WebDriver and any help and suggestions on how I can resolve my issue are welcome.

The html code that I am looking at is:

```html
<html>
<head>
<body class="index">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="masthead">
    <div class="status-bar">
    <div class="app-vpn-selector-container">
    <div id="page_tabs" class="tabs">
    <div class="tab-group monitoring">
    <div class="tab-group-name"> Monitoring </div>
    <div class="tab active"> Status </div>
    <div class="tab"> Events </div>
    <div class="tab"> Reports </div>
    <div class="tab"> Statistics </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-group configuration">
    </div>
    <div id="page_content" class="tab_content">
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

The task I have is to store all the names of the tabs: *Status*, *Events*, *Reports*, *Statistics* and assert that the values exist.

```
List<WebElement> allTabs = webdriver1.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='page_tabs']/div/div"));
```

will get me to the element but I cannot read the attribute values.
Could someone let me know how to resolve it.
I have spent a lot of time reading information online, but could not find a solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

findElements returns a List.  It would give you all the second level divs based on your xpath.  What you need to do once you get the list is to iterate through the elements and call the getText method and verify the text u get..something to the effect

```
 List<WebElement> lstElements = driver.findElementsByXPath("//div[@id='page_tabs']/div/div");

   for (WebElement e : lstElements){
        //Verify e.getText() matches the expected value
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are facing issue in reading the Text (Names of Tabs)...then ***getText()*** is the method you are looking for...

```
String K= Driver.findElements(By.xpath("Main tab Exp")).FindElement(By.xpath("Tab Exp")).getText();
```

I hope this solves the issue. All the best :-)